# Ambiguous literal error when converting SQL Case on SELECT to SQLAlchemy format

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm having problems translating the following CASE Statement on SELECT to SQLAlchemy ORM.  I keep getting the error : "Ambiguous literal: False.  Use the 'text()' function to indicate a SQL expression literal, or 'literal()' to indicate a bound value."

The Case statement checks a variable, and then either returns a column on the database or selects a literal.  The literal is set prior to running the sql statement.

```
  DECLARE @str_cntry_cd varchar(3)
  SELECT COUNTRY_CD,
         CASE WHEN @str_cntry_cd IS NOT NULL THEN RESOLUTION_ID 
              ELSE 10 
           END AS RESOLUTION_ID
  FROM COUNTRY
```

> The SQLAlchemy code looks as follows:

```
        country_tbl = getattr(main_db.Base.classes, "COUNTRY")
        c_res = case([(country_code != None, country_tbl.RESOLUTION_ID),],
                else_ = literal(10)).label("resolution_id")

        programs_sa = main_db.session.query(country_tbl.COUNTRY_CD.label("country_cd"),
                                            c_res).all()
```

The table is as follows:

```
  CREATE TABLE dbo.COUNTRY
  (
      COUNTRY_CD varchar(4) NOT NULL,
      RESOLUTION_ID int NOT NULL
  )
```

SQLAlchemy .9.9
Windows 7
SQL Server 2008 R2
Python 2.7

Answer (score 4):

`country_code != None` is causing the problem.
That evaluates to python's `True`/`False`, which SQLAlchemy doesn't know how to convert to SQL's true/false as it is ambiguous. So you would need to either add the literal true/false for the SQL you are using, by using SQLAlchemy's `text` or `literal` functions. But a better way would be to use the `true` or `false` functions.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.true
http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.false

So you would replace the buggy section of the code with:

`db.false() if country is None else db.true()`

Hope this helps.